# cursor visibility false not working on hardware back press in android

Tags: android, android-keypad

I have 1 edit text in my activity in that when i press a button soft keyboard opens and on hardware backbutton the softkeyboard is closed and cursor should be visible gone..i have implemented as below..Please help me for it..

```
public void onBackPressed()
    {


            brand.setCursorVisible(false);
            brand.clearFocus();

        finish();

    }

}
```

Comment: check whether that method is executing or not??

Comment: after finishing your activity how you get the cursor focus..total activity is lost..

Comment: exactly mann...so pls help me for that what should i do for it..!

Comment: if you dont want cursor from activity creation itself then declare it in oncreate() then edittext cursor is not visible..you are removing cursor visibility in onbackpressed() it is called and finish your activity if you dont finish the activity then cursor visibility is gone..

Comment: @kalyanpvs-can i get some code..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this way**

```
public void onBackPressed()
    {

            if(brand.isCursorVisible()){
                brand.setCursorVisible(false);
                brand.clearFocus();
            }else{
                super.onBackPressed();
            }

    }
```

Comment: its not working my dear bro...pls suggest me some another solution pls...!